# Creating Database templates

Tags: php

what is the best way in php, or some logic... to convert this table template

```
$tmpl ="CREATE TABLE `wpsc_claimed_stock` (
  `product_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `variation_stock_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock_claimed` float NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` datetime NOT NULL,
  `cart_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cart_submitted` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_key` (`product_id`,`variation_stock_id`,`cart_id`),
  KEY `last_activity` (`last_activity`),
  KEY `cart_submitted` (`cart_submitted`)
)";
```

into this format:
note: this snipplet taken from wp-ecommerce (wordpress plugin)

```
$table_name = 'wpsc_claimed_stock';  /* !wpsc_claimed_stock */
$wpsc_database_template[$table_name]['columns']['product_id'] = "bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ";
$wpsc_database_template[$table_name]['columns']['variation_stock_id'] = "bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ";
$wpsc_database_template[$table_name]['columns']['stock_claimed'] = "FLOAT NOT NULL ";
$wpsc_database_template[$table_name]['columns']['last_activity'] = "DATETIME NOT NULL ";
$wpsc_database_template[$table_name]['columns']['cart_id'] = "VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ";
$wpsc_database_template[$table_name]['columns']['cart_submitted'] = "VARCHAR( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ";
$wpsc_database_template[$table_name]['indexes']['unique_key'] = "UNIQUE KEY `unique_key` ( `product_id`,`variation_stock_id`,`cart_id`)";
$wpsc_database_template[$table_name]['indexes']['last_activity'] = "KEY `last_activity` ( `last_activity` )";
$wpsc_database_template[$table_name]['indexes']['cart_submitted'] = "KEY `cart_submitted` ( `cart_submitted` )";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way (perhaps the only way) is to simply write a custom parser. I don't really see any other way to go about it.